# Events do not fire when displaying a VB6 modal form from a C# modal form?

Tags: c#, com, vb6

**EDIT** - I discovered that when the VB6 program runs compiled, the events work normally and there is no problem.

*It is only when the code is running in the VB6 IDE that the events are broken!*

This does not entirely solve the problem because it would be very inefficient development if we can't debug in the IDE; but maybe it provides more insight into the root cause.  I guess the fix that is needed (if possible) is to get the events to work normally / correctly in the IDE.

---

I am loading a modal VB6 form from a modal C# Winform, using COM interop between the two environments. In this configuration (modal-to-modal) *no events will fire in the VB6 form* - e.g,. not even `Form_Load`.

If the forms are loaded non-modally than things do work normally, but of course this does not meet the UI requirements very well.

I would like to understand, if possible, the root cause of this issue and what if anything can be done about it. I have included here the most basic reproduction of the problem I could come up with.

The architecture is that a coordinating object is passed from VB6 to C# code which  acts as wrapper to show the VB6 form.

Sequence of events:

1. Main VB6 program starts
2. VB6 creates a (C#) `ModalCSForm` object and sets its a reference to a `VB6Bridge` object
3. VB6 makes the call to show `ModalCSForm`
4. `ModalCSForm` is shown
5. User clicks button on `ModalCSForm`
6. Button click handler uses `VB6Bridge` object to show `ModalVB6Form`
7. `ModalVB6Form` is shown
8. *No events occur in VB6. No breakpoints will be hit in VB6 code.*

**C# Project:**

Class / form `ModalCSForm`:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public partial class ModalCSForm : Form
{
    ...

    public IVB6Bridge Bridge { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        Bridge.ShowVB6FormModally();
}
```

Interface `IVB6Bridge`:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IVB6Bridge
{
    void ShowVB6FormModally();
}
```

**VB6 Project:**

Main program:

```
Sub main()
    Dim m As New ModalCSForm

    Set m.Bridge = New VB6Bridge
    Call m.ShowDialog
End Sub
```

`ModalVB6Form` code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Label1.Caption = ""  'Doesn't occur, remains "ERASE ME"
End Sub
```

Class `VB6Bridge`:

```
Implements IVB6Bridge

Private Sub IVB6Bridge_ShowVB6FormModally()
    ModalVB6Form.Show FormShowConstants.vbModal
End Sub
```

I've included a screenshot below to demonstrate the problem; obviously the text "ERASE ME" has in fact not been erased, which ought to be the first thing to occur upon form load. Similarly, breakpoints on `Form_Load`, `Form_Initialize`, or anything else in the VB6 form code will NOT be hit.

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while), modal dialogs have their own message pump under the hood, and it won't be using the message pump on the main UI thread.  Happy to be corrected, it's been a while.