# Events raised from a ShowDialog Form aren't raised all the way to a calling vb6 app via com interop?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com-interop

We have a legacy VB6 app where we have been calling .net assemblies for a long time, including displaying WinForms from the .net assembly.  But now I also need to raise events from the .net assembly, from the WinForm, back up to the VB6 app.

This works (the VB6 event fires) when the form is displayed with `.Show`.  But when the form is displayed with `.ShowDialog`, the event doesn't fire in the VB6 app.  And, of course, I need to show the form(s) modally, so that's why `.ShowDialog` is being used.

Code:

Create a .net class library, enabling com interop. This is named ClassLibrary2 when I created it on my machine.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

<ComClass(Class1.ClassId, Class1.InterfaceId, Class1.EventsId)>
Public Class Class1

#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "3E245773-5A31-4B09-A26B-19D2E593395E"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "5A184A72-AE12-4564-83FB-15EEAC8C9A13"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "75C80E42-6B66-4B43-A1FA-BD62C95D117E"
#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub

    Public Event MyEvent(sParm As String)

    Private WithEvents ofrm As Form1

    Public Sub MySub()
        RaiseEvent MyEvent("MySub Entry")
        ofrm = New Form1
        'ofrm.Show()            ' With .Show, all events are raised to calling app
        ofrm.ShowDialog()       ' With .ShowDialog, events from the form are raised to this class, but then subsequently aren't raised to the calling app
        RaiseEvent MyEvent("MySub Exit")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ofrm_MyFormEvent(sParm As String) Handles ofrm.MyFormEvent
        RaiseEvent MyEvent(sParm)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form added to the assembly, then a button added to the form.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Public Event MyFormEvent(sParm As String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent MyFormEvent("Form Closing")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        RaiseEvent MyFormEvent("Form Shown")
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB6 executable application, with a button on the Form, also a reference added to the ClassLibrary2 assembly.

```
Private WithEvents ox As ClassLibrary2.Class1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Set ox = New ClassLibrary2.Class1
  Call ox.MySub
End Sub

Private Sub ox_MyEvent(ByVal sParm As String)
  Debug.Print sParm
End Sub
```

When running all this, the events raised from `MySub` fire the VB6 `ox_MyEvent` event handler.  And when Form1 is displayed with `.Show`, the events raised from the form fire the `ofrm_MyFormEvent` handler, which raises the event further, and the VB6 `ox_MyEvent` event handler fires:

```
MySub Entry
MySub Exit
Form Shown
Form Closing
```

But when Form1 is displayed with `.ShowDialog`, the events raised from the form fires the `ofrm_MyFormEvent` handler, but the event raised from there never fires the VB6 `ox_MyEvent` event handler:

```
MySub Entry
MySub Exit
```

What's happening here? Some kind of VB6 UI thread blocking? But why would the `ShowDialog` be doing that when the events raised from MySub can get through?

Using VS2015, Framework 4.5.2

**Update**

I've run another test, using a .net Winform app (exe) as the calling application, instead of the VB6 code above. Tried calling the ClassLibrary2 assembly as a .net assembly, and also as a COM object. In both cases, the events fired up to the main app as expected:

```
MySub Entry
Form Shown
Form Closing
MySub Exit
```

So it's not a COM issue (or at least not just COM), definitely involving something with VB6?

Comment: Modal dialogs don't communicate with the host until they close. However your dialog code can send messages to the main window generally wm_command. This is how Windows does windowing. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes#modal-dialog-boxes.

Comment: @Mark - I'm not sure I'm understanding your point?  The events raised from the modally displayed form (using the `ShowDialog` method) do fire the event handler in the calling class (Class1).

Comment: This sounds like it has some similarities to this other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101436/events-do-not-fire-when-displaying-a-vb6-modal-form-from-a-c-sharp-modal-form  does anything there help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal dialogs have their own inner message pumps.  Perhaps because that inner message pump is .NET controlled instead of VB6 controlled, there is an incompatibility?  As in, the VB6 message loop is satisfying something VB6 needs that the .NET message pump is not doing?

In any case, personally I moved away from events in COM interop scenarios in favor of using an explicit callback interface.  **The advantage of this is there is no message pump involved at all, you bypass any issues related to that.**

So instead of `Public Event MyEvent(sParm As String)` create an Interface call `IClass1EventListener` or `IClass1CallbackHandler` and give it a method `Sub OnMyFormEvent(sParm As String)`

Then in your VB6 Form use `Implements IClass1EventListener`.

Your code then looks more like this:

```
Private ox As ClassLibrary2.Class1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Set ox = New ClassLibrary2.Class1
  Call ox.MySub(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub IClass1EventListener_OnMyEvent(ByVal sParm As String)
  Debug.Print sParm
End Sub
```

You should take care that to either have the .NET side explicitly clear the callback reference after it completes the ShowDialog or change the method signature to one that your VB6 code can manage it, like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Set ox = New ClassLibrary2.Class1
  Set ox.Listener = Me
  Call ox.MySub()
  Set ox.Listener = Nothing
End Sub
```