# Unable to raise Com Interop event on button click from a Winforms(form) to VB

Tags: c#, vb6, com-interop

I have written a COM Interop visible class library in C#. If i open up the vb6 object browser and look at the members exposed, am seeing an event for each and every single exposed member.

In my interop I have a form with one button, So once the user clicks on the button, the event needs to be invoked but it is not happening even though i have invoked the com visible event on button click. But Alternatively, if i call an public C# function from vb6 and inside the function have invoked the com visibile event, then the event is getting triggered in vb6.0

### Below is my C# code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, EventsInf
{
    public delegate void GetData_delegate(string serviceid);
    public event GetData_delegate GetData;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button click entered");
        GetData?.Invoke("test");
    }
    public void raiseevent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event raised from function");
        GetData?.Invoke("test");
    }
   public void show()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

---

### My Interface:

```
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface Interface
{
    void GetData(string serviceid);
}
```

---

### My EventsInf:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface EventsInf
{
    void raiseevent();
}
```

---

### VB6.0 Code:

```
Private WithEvents test As ClassLibrary5.Form1
Private obj As ClassLibrary5.Class1

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set obj = New ClassLibrary5.Class1
Set test = New ClassLibrary5.Form1
test.raiseevent
Me.Visible = False
obj.Show
End Sub

Private Sub test_GetData(ByVal serviceid As String)

End Sub
```

---

Please refer to the screenshot, where i have converted the C# dll to tlb and added it as reference to my vb6 project. Now on executing the vb 6 project, winform's(form window) gets launched. But, the breakpoint is not getting hit after pressing the 'click me' button.

[image: Screenshot of breakpoint in code]

Comment: Your breakpoint will never get hit. See [Use breakpoints in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022). "You can't set a breakpoint on method signatures..." Try adding a message box to your test_GetData Sub.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru i was able to hit the breakpoint when i delibrately call an com visible function(raiseevent) from vb 6. But i am not able to do the same inside C#events like button click, Form load etc.As u suggested i have set up a msg box to the event in vb 6 but the message box is not displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Events raised from a ShowDialog Form aren't raised all the way to a calling vb6 app via com interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997589/events-raised-from-a-showdialog-form-arent-raised-all-the-way-to-a-calling-vb6) - this is a question I posted a few years ago. If the form does need to be displayed modal (ShowDialog), then callback(s) to the vb6 app can be implemented, rather than raising events

Comment: @MarkL thanks for your comment. It was helpful to me. ShowDialog() does  not work with events. Show() does work in raising com interop events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause:
I have writted 'f1.ShowDialog();' inside my class where f1 is the form object.

Fix:
By rewritting the form code with 'this.Show();' inside a public function resolved this issue.

### C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData?.Invoke("test");
    }    
    public void raiseevent()
    {
        this.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("Event raised from function");
    }
```

---

### VB6.0

```
 Private WithEvents test As ClassLibrary5.Form1
 Private Sub Form_Load()
 Set test = New ClassLibrary5.Form1
 test.raiseevent
 Me.Visible = False
 End Sub

 Private Sub test_GetData(ByVal serviceid As String)

 End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have two different things named `GetData`. This seems like a mistake.

- There is the `event ... GetData` in the Form class.
- And there is the regular function `GetData` in the interface
  `Interface`.

And the form doesn't implement that interface anyway. (And why is it even needed?)

So I think your `test_GetData` doesn't really exist as far as VB6 is concerned. In the IDE you should see `test` in the left dropdown IIRC, and  `GetData` plus any other event in the right dropdown. But it actually just says "General" on the left.

Did you have to type in `Private Sub test_GetData ...` by hand?

Comment: No i haven't typed. It was auto generated. I have invoked getdata inside my class and declared it as event inside interface.

Comment: The interface does not show GetData as an event. It is not the same signature as in the form.

Answer (score -1):

You really ought to follow the standard convention for exposing events. If you want to raise an event that provides text data and raise that event when the user clicks the `Button` then it ought to look like this:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataAvailableEventArgs> DataAvailable;

    protected virtual void OnDataAvailable(DataAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        DataAvailable?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class DataAvailableEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Data { get; }

    public DataAvailableEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

You then raise the event by calling the `OnDataAvailable` method and passing a `DataAvailableEventArgs` object, e.g.

```cs
OnDataAvailable(new DataAvailableEventArgs("test"));
```

You can do that from the `Click` event handler of a `Button` or a `RaiseDataAvailable` method or wherever. The event handler will then be like any other, i.e. the `sender` parameter will be the object that raised the event and the `e` parameter will contain the data, e.g.

```vb
Dim data As String = e.Data
```

If you really want to define your own delegate (maybe COM requires that; not sure) then you can do this:

```cs
public delegate void DataAvailableEventHandler(object sender, DataAvailableEventArgs e);
```

and this:

```cs
public event DataAvailableEventHandler DataAvailable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response John. Tried with the code snippet sent by you but it is of no luck. I have added an attachment with the details in description. Please have a look on it and advise me back.